# graphing time series data in both xaxis and yaxis

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

```
x <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15358, 15359, 15362, 15363, 
15364, 15365), class = "Date"), EndTime = structure(c(1327016747, 
1327166720, 1327361839, 1327446733, 1327533097, 1327619504), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ThresholdTime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), mday = c(20L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L), 
    mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(112L, 112L, 112L, 
    112L, 112L, 112L), wday = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), yday = c(19L, 
    20L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    )), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", 
"wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("Date", 
"EndTime", "ThresholdTime"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to be able to create a graph where xaxis is Date and yaxis is the `EndTime` and draw a `geom_hline` using `ThresholdTime`.

I can strip out the %H and % from `EndTime` to put it in `yaxis`. Basically I am trying to show which data points in `EndTime` breached the `ThresholdTime`.

The problem I am facing is this:

if `Endtime<-c("2012-01-02 09:00:00")` and my threshold is `ThresholdTime` is `c("2012-01-01 08:00:00")`, how would I show this on the graph. If I take the `%H:%M` from `EndTime` it wont look like it breached the `ThresholdTime` but actually it breached the Threshold.

I would appreciate any input in addressing this.

Comment: Have you looked in [the ggplot2 manual](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/index.html)? There's quite a lot of working examples. How far did you get on your own? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hi Eric, I'm pretty familiar with ggplot. I can strip out hits and minutes and put it in yaxis, no problem. I'm running into problems where when actual EndTime is greater than threshold but when I strip out the hours amounts to pu in yaxis, it may show as threshold time is bigger than endtime.

Comment: Are you hoping to plot the 'EndTime' and 'ThreshholdTime' as minutes from midnight of the current day?  Ewwh... just noticed you have a POSIXlt column. Those cause no end of difficulties. Should convert to POSIXct immediately!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the hours and minutes by themselves do not capture all your information, you also need the day (or relative day, at least). Or another way to think of it, you need relative time.

```
x$end <- difftime(x$EndTime, as.POSIXct(x$Date), units="hours")
x$thresh <- difftime(x$ThresholdTime, as.POSIXct(x$Date), units="hours")
```

ggplot doesn't handle difftimes directly, so just convert to their numerical equivalent which is in hours since we forced it to be. Then it is just a little formatting of the labels to look like hours and minutes.

```
ggplot(x, aes(Date, as.numeric(end))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=as.numeric(thresh))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(dt) {
    paste0(sprintf("%02d",floor(dt)),":",sprintf("%02d",floor(60*(dt-floor(dt)))))
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Brain Diggs. this is great. Just a quick question. Would it be possible to show yaxis from 00:00 23:59? I see that you put 25:00, 30:00

Comment: I really appreciate this. What I am trying to show is this: Put 00:00 through 23:59 on yaxis. For a given data, show the EndTime in terms of %H:%M and ThresholdTime in %H:%M. I need to be able to show if EndTime is greater than Threshold, the points should be above the geom_hline. I am not sure I can do this in ggplot.

Comment: Given that the day of EndTime and ThresholdTime are not even the same, I don't see how any representation using just %H:%M could show what you want (regardless of which graphing system you are using).

Comment: if the day in EndTime and ThresholdTime is the same it is doable. The challenge is, if the Day in EndTime higher than ThresholdTime, then I am not sure it will be doable. I am trying to show the time in yaxis. Trying to show the EndTime relative to ThresholdTime.